# Using Python send email utility adding extra character(!) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below source code in my python script to send an email which basically reads the html file and send it to email it.The problem is when the email comes and it shows the contents on the email it is having some extra(!) words/character.I thought maybe html is having but after checking the html file there is no such words/character.

I am creating multiple html small files and them merging into a single html file and sending or showing those contents in the email.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMETEXT
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

AUTH_FROM_EMAIL = 'abc@email.com'
MAIL_HOST = 'smtp-abc.net'

def drop_email(sfrom=None,lstto=None,sub=None,body=None):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    
    msg[''] = subj
    msg[''] = sfrom
    for sto in sendtolst:
    msg['To'] = sto

ishtml = 'html' in body.lower()
msg.attach(MIMETEXT(body, 'html' if ishtml else plain))

s = smtplib.SMTP(MAIL_HOST)
s.sendmail(AUTH_FROM_EMAIL, sendtolist, msg.as_string())


def main()
    a(name)
    sfrom = 'abc.text@abc.com'
    sto1 = 'next.time@abc.com'
    text = 'Greeting'
    html_file = open('abc.html')
    html = html_file.read()
    subj = 'hello'
    try:
       drop_email(sfrom, [sto1], subj,html)
    except (Exception) as e:
       print(e)
```

Output(html Table) something like that(2ND line shows ! in email whereas html file doesn't have this:

```
 ABC       ID    TYPE   DATE        TS
 201-0403  124   MICE   20211004    201-01-04 09:30:00
 201-0403  123   NICE   202!11004   201-01-04 10:30:00
 201-0403  121   MICE   20211004    201-01-04 10:30:00
```

---

```
<html>
<style> table , th, td {border:1px solid black;}</style>
<body>
<h2>TABLE STATUS 20211004</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th style="background-color:#00FF00">ABC</th>
<th style="background-color:#00FF00">ID</th>
<th style="background-color:#00FF00">TYPE</th>
<th style="background-color:#00FF00">DATE</th>
<th style="background-color:#00FF00">TS</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>201-0403</td><td>124</td><td>MICE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>201-0403</td><td>122</td><td>NCE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>201-0403</td><td>123</td><td>NICE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
<tr><td>201-0403</td><td>125</td><td>RICE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Output of print(repr(msg.as_string())):

```
'Content-Type: multipart/aternative; boundary="=========0711723306722683063=="\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n
Subject: HELLO\nFROM: abc@tetx.com\n
TO:unkonw@text.com\n\n--=============0711723306722683063==\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n
   <html>
    <style> table , th, td {border:1px solid black;}</style>
    <body>
    <h2>TABLE STATUS 20211004</h2>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#00FF00">ABC</th>
    <th style="background-color:#00FF00">ID</th>
    <th style="background-color:#00FF00">TYPE</th>
    <th style="background-color:#00FF00">DATE</th>
    <th style="background-color:#00FF00">TS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>201-0403</td><td>124</td><td>MICE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>201-0403</td><td>122</td><td>NCE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>201-0403</td><td>123</td><td>NICE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>201-0403</td><td>125</td><td>RICE</td><td>20211004</td><td>201-01-04 09:30:00</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>\n\n
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your post

Comment: Can you share the real HTML file? The output you've shown is just tab-separated values (TSV)

Comment: @OneCricketeer updated the html file for one table

Comment: @OneCricketeer updated the rint(repr(msg.as_string()))

Comment: Alright, well, in the output there, you can see `20211004` is intact, so sounds like the problem is maybe with the mail server or the client you're using to read the message... You could also download an EML file from your mail client, then open that as text